# Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "id()", [...]"__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

For the life of me I can't get this to work. I have a Many-To-One relationship between **Round** and **Program** Entity. **Program** is related to **ProgramDetail** by One-To-Many.

Basically **Round** < Many-To-One > **Program** < One-To-Many > **ProgramDetail**.

**Round** Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Program", inversedBy="rounds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $programs;
```

**Program** Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Round", mappedBy="programs")
 */
private $rounds;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProgramDetail", mappedBy="program")
 */
private $details;
```

**ProgramDetail** Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Program", inversedBy="details")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $program;
```

Here is how i query all existing **Rounds** with according to it **ProgramDetail**.

```
// RoundRepository.php

public function getRoundsWithProgramDetails()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('round')
                ->leftJoin('round.programs', 'rp')
                ->leftJoin('rp.details', 'pd')
                ->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

Here is how I try output it

```
{% for round in rounds %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ round.year }}</td>
    <td>{{ round.programs.details.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ round.scoreSendDate|date('m-d-Y') }}</td>
    <td>{{ round.sampleSendDate|date('m-d-Y') }}</td>
    <td>{{ round.resultSendDate|date('m-d-Y') }}</td>
    <td>{{ round.status }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If I get this done I'll at once have like 40% progress on my project since I have mostly such problems. Any help appreciated

Comment: Try `->leftJoin('AppBundle:ProgramDetails, 'pd')`

Comment: @geoB I use symfony 4 and dont make use of bundles

Comment: `round.programs.details.id` - what are you expecting here? You're trying to access the ID property of a collection (i.e. *all* of the program's details)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is triggered by this line `{{ round.programs.details.id }}`?

Now `round.programs.details` is a collection of ProgramDetail entities, since it is a OneToMany relation. That is why in the error message `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` is mentioned. You basically try to access the `id` attribute of a collection of ProgramDetail entities, which obviously doesn't exist.

I assume the relation should rather be OneToOne instead of ManyToOne/OneToMany, because in the current form every Program can have *multiple* ProgramDetails assigned and they are therefore represented as a list/collection of entities and not as a single entity.

If not, you either need to specify an index within that list to get the id from like that: `{{ round.programs.details.first.id }}` or in general find another way of working with a *list of ProgramDetail entities* there.

Comment: First, I thought so, but I'm watching knpuniversity as I work on this project. In one of the videos about relationships they mention not to bother yourself with OneToOne relation as it is not there. Now I switched it to OneToOne on Program <> ProgramDetail and it works... Thanks!